# How to determine if a file is a symbolic link or a .lnk shortcut file in MSYS2 (mintty) terminal?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, msys2

Is there a command in MSYS2 terminal that can be used to determine whether a file is a symbolic link or a windows shortcut .lnk file? For example:

```
$ touch a.txt
# Create a symbolic link:
$ MSYS=winsymlinks:nativestrict ln -s a.txt b.txt
# Create a .lnk shortcut file:
$ MSYS=winsymlinks ln -s a.txt c.txt
$ ls -l
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 hakon hakon 0 Jan 22 20:54 a.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hakon hakon 5 Jan 22 20:54 b.txt -> a.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hakon hakon 5 Jan 22 20:55 c.txt -> a.txt
```

From the above output, it is not possible to distinguish between the two types of links.

Note: I found that I can use `fsutil` to check for symbolic links, but then I must know in advance that the file is a symbolic link.

Comment: I don't know what relationship there is there between .lnk files and bash done in Ming in windows, but  a .lnk file would a)have a .lnk extension and b)if you cat it then you'd see .lnk related junk  `$cat blah.lnk` <-- outputs junk from the lnk file.

Comment: @barlop I want to check from the terminal. There the extension is `.txt` for both types right?

Comment: also according to https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/HEAD/docs/windows.md  the nativestrict option thing is to do with whether a file is copied or wheher a symboic link is actually made. Where windows .lnk files come into it I have no idea

Comment: a file would have the same extension whether looking from the terminal or not looking from the terminal (do ensure windows GUI is set to not hide file extensions!)

Comment: @barlop You can see from the output in my question when I type `ls -l` it shows only `.txt` files

Comment: *"do ensure windows GUI is set to not hide file extensions"* I am using terminal window, what do you mean by windows GUI?

Comment: You wrote "I want to check from the terminal. **There** the extension is .txt for both types right?" <--   That wording you used suggested that you were suggesting that you thought that maybe files could be .txt in one place and not .txt elsewhere.. A txt file that is .txt in one place is .txt in another.

Comment: @barlop *"It's .txt, wherever"* Ok! Sorry for bad wording I did not meant that the file ended in .lnk but that the type of the file is a LNK shortcut file, if that makes sense) .. but anyway that is not the issue I am trying to solve. How can I determine whether `b.txt` is a symbolic link or LNK shortcut file from the terminal?

Comment: well if you have a .lnk shortcut file then if you do `$cat blah.lnk` then you see some encoded stuff  Whereas for a symbolic link if you do `cat blah.abc` it should show the file that it links to.  I have never run into making a .lnk shortcut file from the cmd line and you aren't doing it there either.. You're creating a symbolic link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118811/discussion-between-barlop-and-hakon-haegland).

Answer (score 1):

You may use the free Nirsoft utility
[NTFSLinksView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ntfs_links_view.html):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there a way I can avoid the gui and use it as command line query tool?

Comment: It has command-line parameters for creating a text file.